# Is that possible to integrate EntityFramework/ADO.NET DLL with Core app?

Tags: entity-framework

Is it possible to integrate EF/ADO.NET DLL(.Net Framework Class Library) with Core app (.NET Core Console app) ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that possible to integrate EF/ADO.NET DLL(.Net Framework Class Library) with Core app (.NET Core Console app) ?!

Currently no.  If the .dll targets .NET Framework and uses EF 6, it can't be loaded in a .NET Core application.

You can migrate the .DLL to use [EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/), or update (still in preview) the .DLL to use EF 6.3 and target .NET Core 3.  See [What’s next: EF Core 3.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/12/04/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-2/#comments)